# Angular2 routing, error 404 when refreshing path (on live server)

Tags: angular, router

My problem has probably no solution and everybody knows it or solution is just there, but I just can't see it.

I followed this tutorial to the letter :
https://coursetro.com/posts/code/19/A (I'm not sure shall I post files here...or link is enough)

Clean project created with angular-cli beta 19-3

It is basic Angular 2 single page app router demo and it does work like a charm on localhost:4200.

By 'like a charm' I mean that when I refresh the page at root (http://localhost:4200) project loads, and when I manually point to localhost:4200/services and hit enter it goes to the correct page.

However, when I build project (ng build --prod) and serve it via MAMP or upload it to my website (of course to the root folder) it doesn't work this way anymore.

Page loads at root (mydomain.com) and nav works fine, but whenever I want to either refresh the page or type in path manually and hit enter it gives me an error 404:

Not Found
The requested URL /services was not found on this server.

Please believe me I was looking for answers before asking here, but the closest I've found was from begining of the year. Router has changed since then and the solution isn't applicable anymore.

I realize that physically given path '/services' doesn't exist on server since it is only idea (route) declared within the app. 
Something rings the bell that paths should be 'translated' into urls, but I'm looking for some solution digestable for someone new to js and angular.

On the other hand I think that it must be doable since apps/pages you guys show here also highlighted on builtwithangular2.com work just like expected.

One more thing maybe - of course base href was set as the project set it. I also moved it to the first row under  Tag, but no results.

I'd be really grateful if someone could point me to the right resources.

Thank you
Kind regards
Mac